# Is $\pi$! irrational?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, irrational-numbers, pi

The factorial value of $\pi$ can be found using the gamma function like so:
$$\Gamma \left( \pi +1 \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty {s^{\pi} e^{ - s}\,\mathrm{d}s} ≈ 7.1880827$$

This, however, raises the question of if this number is irrational. It is well-known that $\pi$ is irrational, but is $\pi!$ irrational too?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124980/discussion-on-question-by-supermug-is-pi-irrational).